# Change jQueryUI Dialog button text within open method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Upon opening a jQueryUI Dialog, I would like to perform a GET request, and based on the response, change the button text.  After hours of struggling, I finally got the following working.  Is this really the best/only?  Thanks

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    open        : function() {
        var dialog=$(this);
        $.get('ajax.php', function (data) {
            var buttons=dialog.dialog( "option", "buttons" );
            buttons[1].text=(data==1)?"CANCEL":"CLOSE";
            var buttons=dialog.dialog( "option", "buttons" ,buttons);
        });
    },
    buttons     : [
        {
            text    : 'SAVE',
            click    : function() {}
        },
        {
            text    : 'CANCEL',
            click    : function() {}
        }
    ]    
});
```

Comment: why you dont make your ajax.php call first and open the dialog after the response?

Comment: @silly.  What would you change after the ajax call?  What about the way I am copying the entire button object, and reinitializing the dialog with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the button text like this...

the below given is without ajax

```
function setbutton(button1, button2) {
var btns = {};
btns[button1] = function() {
    //your function
   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
};
btns[button2] = function() {
    // Do nothing
    //your function
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
};

document.getElementById('dialogshow').innerHTML = "<div>open with given button text</div>";


$( "#dialogshow" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 450,
    height: 200,
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    modal: true,
    buttons: btns
});
}
$('.test').click(function() {
setbutton('start', 'End');//in here button name you want..
});
```

[See the Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/5sF2M/2/)

Comment: Thanks Dinesh.  Interesting approach.  It seems cleaner than my approach.